# iOS 14.1 showing RSSI of 19 randomly

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Since updating to iOS 14.1 my iPhone has randomly showed a BLE device with RSSI of positive 19. A positive RSSI isn't possible, and I've never seen it before until iOS 14.1. I know 127 is a hardcoded values for "none" in the BLE reference. Does anyone know what 19 is or why my iPhone is reporting positive RSSI values?

Here is a list of random reading:

```
-74
-74
-73
-73
-71
19
-79
-80
-79
-80
-76
-76
-75
-74
```

So my BLE device regularly reports about -70 to -80, but then randomly 19.

=====

From looking through iOS sysdiagnose logs I see that bluetoothd logs a message of a new "rssi level is 19" before reporting to my app the RSSI:

```
Nov  4 17:36:24 bluetoothd[506] <Notice>: Applying RSSI offset of 0 to 27, new rssi level is 19
Nov  4 17:36:24 bluetoothd[506] <Notice>: Applying RSSI offset of 0 to -74, new rssi level is -74
Nov  4 17:36:24 bluetoothd[506] <Notice>: Matched UUID 6712B74E-8D81-465E-8E07-09C1923C11C6 for device "<private>"
Nov  4 17:36:24 bluetoothd[506] <Notice>: Matched UUID 6712B74E-8D81-465E-8E07-09C1923C11C6 for device "<private>"
Nov  4 17:36:24 MyApp(MyAppLibrary)[4380] <Notice>: [HomeViewController:801] Discovered 6712B74E-8D81-465E-8E07-09C1923C11C6 19
Nov  4 17:36:24 MyApp(MyAppLibrary)[4380] <Notice>: [HomeViewController:801] Discovered 6712B74E-8D81-465E-8E07-09C1923C11C6 -74
```

Comment: A small correction: the possible range according to the hci standard is -127 to +20, or the special value 127 which means not available.

Comment: I've also edited my question with relevant sysdiagnose logs mentioning an "RSSI Offset of 0 to 27"

Comment: @Emil I see in the BLE Spec 5.2 section "7.7.65.2  LE Advertising Report event" it says those ranges. But what does a positive RSSI value mean? Why is it always exactly 19?

Comment: The unit is dBm. So 19 dBm is 10^(19/10) mW, which is very high. A value of -74 dBm is 10^(-74/10) mW. The only guess is that there is some bug somewhere, since these results are not realistic.